# Is the Spectral Radius of a Primitive Matrix Bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a primitive matrix. If I add a nonnegative matrix $\epsilon E$ ($\epsilon > 0$), does the following limit for the spectral radius exist
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to \infty} \rho(A+\epsilon E)$$
or does it grow without bound? Numerical experiments for my specific matrices indicate that the spectral radius grows without bound but I want to see if there are general results. I make no assumptions on the form of matrix $E$.

Comment: This may not be important, but in the original definition of primitive matrix (given by Frobenius, I think), $A$ is not required to be nonnegative. Is your $A$ nonnegative?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, $A$ is nonnegative.

Comment: You do need to assume that $E\ne 0$. For large enough $\epsilon$, $A$ ends up looking like a small perturbation of $\epsilon E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it grows without a bound. To see that, first note that for nonnegative matrices Gelfand's formula implies that the spectral radius function is monotonic. That is, if $X\ge Y\ge0$, then $\rho(X)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|X^k\|^{1/k}\ge\lim_{k\to\infty}\|Y^k\|^{1/k}=\rho(Y)$.

Suppose $E\ne0$. Since $A$ is nonnegative and primitive, $A^m$ and $A^{m+1}$ are positive for some positive integer $m$. Therefore
$$
(A+\epsilon E)^{m+1}\ge P+\epsilon Q:=A^{m+1}+\epsilon A^mE\ge0.
$$
$P=A^{m+1}$ is positive. Since $Q=A^mE$ is nonzero and nonnegative, it has a positive entry. If this is a diagonal entry $q_{ii}$, we look at the diagonal entry $p_{ii}+\epsilon q_{ii}$ of $P+\epsilon Q$. If this is an off-diagonal entry $q_{ij}>0$, we look at the principal $2\times2$ submatrix $(P+\epsilon Q)(\mathcal I,\mathcal I)$, where $\mathcal I=\{i,j\}$ and
$$
(P+\epsilon Q)(\mathcal I,\mathcal I)
\ge \pmatrix{p_{ii}&p_{ij}+\epsilon q_{ij}\\ p_{ji}&p_{jj}}
\ge C := p\pmatrix{1&r\epsilon\\ 1&1}
$$
for some $p,r>0$. So, when $\epsilon\to\infty$, we have $p_{ii}+\epsilon q_{ii}\to\infty$ in the first case and $\rho(C)=p(1+\sqrt{r\epsilon})\to\infty$ in the second case. The monotonicity of spectral radius thus implies that $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty}\rho(P+\epsilon Q)=\infty$. Hence $\rho(A+\epsilon E)\ge\rho(P+\epsilon Q)^{1/(m+1)}$ is unbounded.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow why either some diagonal entry of $B_{\epsilon}$ is greater than $p+\epsilon q$ for some positive constants $p$ and $q$ or some principal submatrix is greater than $C_{\epsilon}$. From where do you obtain these statements?

Comment: I understand that the positive entry in the matrix $Q$ drives the spectral radius. However, I found myself wondering where your first inequality comes from. Why do you look at this inequality first?

Comment: The first one $(A+\epsilon E)^{m+1} \ge A^{m+1} + \epsilon A^{m} E.$ Do you use this inequality in order to assure that the matrix $Q = A^{m}E$ is both nonnegative and nonzero?

Comment: @Mario That's part of the reason. I need $P>0,\ Q\ge0$ and $Q\ne0$. All three of them. If $P$ is not positive, $P+\epsilon Q$ may have a constant spectral radius (e.g. consider $P=0$ and $Q$ is any nilpotent Jordan block). If $Q=0$, the contribution of $\epsilon$ would come from second or higher order term, making calculation of eigenvalues difficult. Given that $P>0$, if $Q$ is not nonnegative, I cannot use the monotonicity of spectral radius.